# Get Post Id of the Live Facebook Video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming, live-video

Is there any Facebook API available to get PostId of the live video by giving live-video-id?

I need to post comments under live video. Unfortunately Facebook doesn't support comment creation by live-video-id ([Live Video Comments API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/comments/)), but it is possible to post comments under live videos by making POST request to `/v2.8/{post-id}/comments` endpoint. Now I can't find an end-point to get post-id from live-video-id.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook team, there is no available API for leaving comments under live video.